# How to fix 'For loop' as Token index is not increment

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pexpect

I am working on x3.py file and calling check_vpn() and connect_vpn() functions from mon_back.py file. When I call check_vpn function in x3.py It's working fine but problem is when I call connect_vpn() the token index[i] is not incremented.

`This is x3.py`

```
import json
import mon_back

obj = mon_back.vpn()
obj.check_vpn()

with open('auth1.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    token = data["vpn_detail"]["tokens"]
    for i in range(len(token)):
        token1 = token[i]
        print(token[i])
        print(token1)
        i = i+1   
        obj.connect_vpn(token1)
```

```
mon_back.py
```

```
import ------
class vpn():
    vpn_bin= '/home/'

    def check_vpn(self):  
        myCmd = os.popen('ps aux | grep vpnc').read()
        for():
            if():
            return true

    def connect_vpn(self,token1):
        child = pexpect.spawn(self.vpn_bin + 'connectCiscoVpn_Banglore username', encoding='utf-8')
        child.expect('com')
        child.sendline(token1)
        h = child.expect(['authentication unsuccessful','no response from target','VPNC started in background', '[#\$] '])
        if h==0 or h==1:         
            with open('auth1.json') as json_file:  
            data = json.load(json_file)
            token = data["vpn_detail"]["tokens"]
            for i in range(len(token)):
                token1 = token[i]
                i = i+1  
                self.connect_vpn(token1)                              
        elif h==2:
            print("##################   VpN Connected..   ###########")                
            sys.exit()
```

I just get the same token every time when I run this code, If authentication unsuccessfull then It's going to increment the value of `i = i + 1` but after reenter in for loop the value of `i` is  become zero. I expect the value of `i` is increment when its going into for loop every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `x3.py` file first and check your code flow correctly you will find that you are resting your tokens.

first you read the first token from opening the file and passing it to `connect_vpn` method of `mon_back.py` . 
Then in `mon_back.py` file in you are checking for value of `h` if condition you are again opening the same file and reading the token so it again takes the first token. after that you are calling the same method `self.connect_vpn`
and again checking the condition of `h` and reopening the file so again it reads the first token.

Please check your code flow and correct it.

One solution is that in if condition you don't need to write anything just return from there or print message or error log and return so that flow can go to `x3.py` and take the second token to comeback to `connect_vpn` method

Answer (score 0):

The  changes  is in below  for   loop, Thanks @pawan. I have changed this for loop in both the files.

```
            if h==0 or h==1:               
                with open('auth1.json') as json_file:  
                    data = json.load(json_file)
                    token = data["vpn_detail"]["tokens"]
                    for i in range(0,len(token)): 
                        token1 = token[i]
```

After changes in for loop it will increment the token index. Thanks.